# MariaDB event scheduler not starting after migrating MySQL to MariaDB. Ignoring config file

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I've my upgraded my system from Debian 8 to Debian 9.

MySQL Version on Debian 8 (before upgrade) - 5.5.58-0+deb8u1-log (Debian)

MariaDB version on Debian 9 (after upgrade): 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.1

Problem is, that when i add:

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler = on
```

To /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf and restart the mysql server, the event scheduler is still disabled according to following query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler';

| event_scheduler | OFF   |
```

Is there anything special about mariadb to explain why is it not starting?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had custom global umask.. which results in wrong permissions on files inside /etc/mysql. Had to fix them manually and suddenly scheduler started working.